# How to tell when a dll is loaded

Tags: c++

I have some c++ code that loads debug symbols on Windows the first time its called, but (obviously) delay loaded dlls aren't being picked up if they're loaded after the first time the code is hit. Its not feasible for me to reload the symbols every time my routine is hit, so I was hoping there was some sort of callback where I could be notified if a dll is delay loaded.

Comment: I think some people are confused about your problem. You have code that loads debug symbols for all currently loaded DLLs. Some DLLs in the program are delay-loaded, so when you code runs, it doesn't get symbols for them (because they're not loaded yet). You want to be notified of any subsequently loaded DLLs so you can update your symbol list. The alternative is to reload the symbols anew every time your code is called just in case the DLL list has changed, but that's wasteful. You'd prefer to *know* whether or not the DLL list has changed. Yes?

Comment: @RobKennedy - thats exactly it. I'm especially interested in COM dlls

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you can write your own delay load helper function instead of using the default one.  Not much point in going into detail in this question, it is well explained in the MSDN Library.  The starting page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx), things get interesting at "Understanding the helper function" section.

Comment: Obviously this works only if it's only *your* dll that delay-loads other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two ways of catching mostly everything (mostly cause this won't get manually mapped files), you can place a system wide hook on `LoadLibraryA\W` and `LoadLibraryEx`(or the kernel mapping and PEB linking functions from Ldr*) and check if the calling process matches your process. Else, you can make your program attach to itsself and wait for the dll load debug event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679302(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for Debugging Events
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679302(v=VS.85).aspx

Seems like you're looking for LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem to be very cleary. But still I assume that what you're looking for is [`DllMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Its the entry point of DLL.  Read the documentation for details.

And since you're talking about delay load, maybe you need to look at [`LoadLibraryEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well. Its used to load DLL into the proccess memory.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I want to know in one dll when another dll has been loaded into the process

Comment: @Steve: You can call a function residing in `a.dll` from `DllMain()` of `b.dll`.